# Get the element I have hovered when I drop an element with jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How can I get the element which I hovered at the moment of dropping the dragged element?

All elements in the container have the class .droppableYElement in common.

```
 $("#container").droppable({
        accept: ".droppableXElement",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function (event, ui) {

            alert("I am dropped");

  // How can I get the element which I hovered at the moment of dropping the dragged element?


        }
    });
```

Comment: $(this) in the drop function will get you the element being hovered or the element in which the draggable is dropped. Try it

Comment: I always get the parent container of the dropped area not the div within that area when I hovered and dropped the dragged element. I do NOT want to ge the area in which the draggable is dropped. I want the element my mouse pointer was over when I drop the element.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with relevant HTML?

Comment: Check your event for currentTarget? `event.currentTarget` jquery wrap `$()` that in your drop callback and see if that is what you're looking for?

Comment: The event.currentTarget seems like my window object? nothing usefull or do I look wrong at it? This $(event.currentTarget); did not help there is nothing useful in the result object.

Comment: @KK http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/XJMMxV Here you can play with it. I could not setup a full demo because in the final version It is only possible to drag/drop elements from a 2nd div. It should not be possible to drag/drop the elements within the itemContainer just elements from outside. Maybe there is some tricky registering of hover event on all items in the itemContainer... I have no idea.

Comment: @Elisa Try the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/528/

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#itemContainer > div").each(function (index, element) {
        $(element).draggable();
    });

    $("#itemContainer").droppable({
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var element = document.elementFromPoint(event.pageX, event.pageY);
//Get the coordinates of mouse and using these coordinates, find the element. 
            console.log(element); //Element which was hovered.
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Dude! you rock! You know what I already wanted to do? Bad things came to my mind like: subscribe the mouser over event to all children of the itemContainer and write in the event $(this) to a globalVariable.lastHoveredElement and when I am in the drop function I would just get the value from lastHoveredElement :P

Comment: :D anyway this saves your experiments

Comment: @K K it worked fine in your demo but now that I have implemented it into production code the element I get from the points is not the div its the whole footer.html ??? What the heck! I am lost...It worked this afternoon now not anymore also I reverted all back argh...even deleted the cache.

Comment: I have a guess maybe its because the divs have svg files and no background like transparent color... which gives the footer we will see...

Comment: @Elisa If you can share the production link then I it will be easier for me to look on the issue.

Comment: I solved it bro by using .clientX and .clientY because our side/document has scrollbars see this: http://www.zehnet.de/2010/11/19/document-elementfrompoint-a-jquery-solution/ I am happy!